# Holding dynamic Controls on postback not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I get this error and do not find the problem:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My Code:

Page Init:

```
else if (Request.QueryString["CompanyID"] != null)
{
   pnlComp.Visible = true;
   if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Generated"]) != "true")
   {
      createCompSite();
      ViewState["Generated"] = "true";
   }                
}
```

Page Load:

```
 Verification.Check();
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
    sFilter= null;
    FillGridviewAndValues();
 }
 if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Generated"]) == "true")
    createCompSite();
```

Function:

```
TableHeaderRow tHRow = new TableHeaderRow();
TableHeaderCell tHeader = new TableHeaderCell();
tHeader.Text = dr.Field<string>("Loc");
tHRow.Cells.Add(tHeader);
tblCompLoc1.Rows.Add(tHRow);

DataTable dtCat = new DataTable();
dtCat = SQLCon.SQLCommand_DokuTool("SELECT CL.ID, C.CatName FROM TBL_Ref_CatLoc AS CL, TBL_Category AS C WHERE C.CatID = CL.CatID AND CL.LocID = '" + dr.Field<Guid>("ID").ToString() + "' AND CL.Approved='True' ORDER BY CatName ASC");

foreach (DataRow dr2 in dtCat.Rows)
{
   //Working as plain Text
   //TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
   //TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
   //tCell.Text = dr2.Field<string>("CatName");
   //tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
   //tblCompLoc1.Rows.Add(tRow);


   //Not working as Hyperlink or Btn
     TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
     TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
     HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
     hl.EnableViewState=true;
     hl.Text = dr2.Field<string>("CatName");
     string gLocID = SQLCon.SQLCommand_User("SELECT ID FROM TBL_Location WHERE fCompanyID = '"+sRequest+"' AND City + ', ' + Street1 ='"+tHeader.Text+"'").Rows[0].Field<Guid>("ID").ToString();
     string gCatID = SQLCon.SQLCommand_DokuTool("SELECT CatID FROM TBL_Category WHERE CatName='"+hl.Text+"'").Rows[0].Field<Guid>("CatID").ToString();
     string sRequestedCat = SQLCon.SQLCommand_DokuTool("SELECT ID FROM TBL_Ref_CatLoc WHERE LocID = '"+gLocID+"' AND CatID='"+gCatID+"'").Rows[0].Field<Guid>("ID").ToString();                        
     hl.NavigateUrl="~/Default?ID="+sRequestedCat;
     tCell.Controls.Add(hl);
     tRow.Controls.Add(tCell);
     tblCompLoc1.Rows.Add(tRow);
}
```

I want to create a Table which is filled from DataBase and can look different on each site and every Table Cell should have a different Link where it leads the user. The table creation starts on page init.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: omg!, you have some other problems in that code.  there is serious security flaws , like sql injection  you need to take care of before fixing any output problems!

Comment: thats no problem ;) not possible there is more code and security things